# How to copy entire row from one sheet with specific value to another sheet (in different workbook)using macros

Tags: vba, excel

As a beginner in field of macros, I need advise on how to copy/paste an entire row if column R has value = "YES", from sheet "database", to the next available blank row in sheet2.

Also Sheet2 is another file/workbook at location `"C:\Users\Desktop\KPIs"`

Comment: Which cell in column R is `=YES`? One way to get started is to start the macro recorder, perform the operation, and then stop the recorder and examine the auto-generated code.

Comment: It can be any cell in Column R. And advice helped a lot to get sense of macros.

Answer (score 0):

Example assumes the workbook you want to paste to is already open.

If `R1` is "YES" then it copies row 3 to row 3 in the Target workbook

```
Sub CopyRow()
    Dim copyRng As Range

    If Worksheets("Database").Range("R1") = "YES" Then
        Worksheets("Database").Range("A3").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Target").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this is not helping :( tell me if you need more clarification? As I have mentioned it can any cell (more than one) in column R can be = "YES"